# Тестовое задание на собеседовании

Tags: php

Мне перед собеседованием на позицию помощника php программиста, задали задание:
[Текст задания.](http://pastebin.com/K9vBMPD9)
[Исходный код программы.](http://pastebin.com/Tjrzs8ut)

Можете подсказать, есть ли у меня синтаксические или логические ошибки в коде, которые я не усмотрел ? И вообще, правильно ли я сделал, исходя из задания ?

Comment: @eicto, тогда как мне переписать все это ? у меня просто это была единственная идея..

Comment: Да еще и статическая переменная вне класса :рукалицо:
Вы уверены, что этот цикл делает то, что задумано?

    foreach($arrValue as $value)
    {
        $value["color"] = rand(0,1);
        ...

Может все-таки нужна ссылка $arrValue as &$value?

Comment: @Равнодушный, причем здесь синглетон, если в ТЗ:

    $apple_1 = new apple('green');

???

Comment: @MDJHD при том, что в тестах `echo apple::$apples[0]->color` почему само задание так сделано это вопрос компетенции тестирующего.

Comment: @eicto, на счет одиночки я действительно погорячился - при первом прочтение придумал излишне всеохватывающее решение. А задание очень даже неплохое. ТС, например, отсеяло сразу...)

Comment: ну я про идею хранить все яблоки в классе яблока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

```
class apple
    {
    const SPOIL_HOURS = 5;
    public static $apples = array();
    public static $currentHour = 0;
    public static $defaultColors = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
    public $color;
    private $grownHour;
    private $fallenHour;
    private $ind;
    private $size = 1.0;

    public function __construct($color = NULL)
        {
        if (!is_string($color))
            $color = self::$defaultColors[array_rand(self::$defaultColors)];
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->grownHour = self::$currentHour;
        $this->ind = count(self::$apples);
        self::$apples[$this->ind] = $this;
        }

    public function __get($name)
        {
        return (isset($this->{$name})) ? $this->{$name} : NULL;
        }

    public function is_fallen()
        {
        return (is_null($this->fallenHour)) ? false : true;
        }

    public function is_spoiled()
        {
        if (!$this->is_fallen())
            return false;

        if (self::$currentHour - $this->fallenHour < self::SPOIL_HOURS)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        }

    public function eat($eatPerc)
        {
        if (!$this->is_fallen() || $this->is_spoiled())
            return false;
        $eatPerc = min(100, floatval($eatPerc));
        $eatSize = abs($eatPerc / 100);
        $this->size = max(0, $this->size - $eatSize);

        if ($this->size == 0)
            unset(self::$apples[$this->ind]);
        return $this->size;
        }

    public function fall_to_ground()
        {
        if (!is_null($this->fallenHour))
            return false;
        $this->fallenHour = self::$currentHour;
        return true;
        }

    public static function lost_hour()
        {
        return ++self::$currentHour;
        }
    }
```

Применение:

```
$apple = new apple();
echo 'grown: #'.$apple->ind.'; color: '.$apple->color.'<br/>';

$apple->eat(50);  // <- false — яблоко на дереве
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 1 — время мира: 1 час
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 2 — время мира: 2 часа
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 3 — время мира: 3 часа
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 4 — время мира: 4 часа
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 5 — время мира: 5 часов
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 6 — время мира: 6 часов
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено

$apple->fall_to_ground();  // <- true — яблоко упало
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 7 — время мира: 7 часов
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- false — не испорчено
$apple->eat(50);       // <- 0.5 — откусили половину
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 8 — время мира: 8 часов
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 9 — время мира: 9 часов
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 10 — время мира: 10 часов
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 11 — время мира: 11 часов
apple::lost_hour();    // <- 12 — время мира: 12 часов
$apple->is_spoiled();  // <- true — испорчено
$apple->eat(50);  // <- false — яблоко испорчено
```

Подошел к вопросу так, чтобы как можно меньше привязываться ко флагам — при том, что все можно вполне безболезненно проверять налету. На мой взгляд, гораздо важнее сохранять как можно больше «стартовой» информации — это придает гибкости.

Answer (score 1):

Накидал примерный прототипчик класса, основные методы не реализовывал, оставляю их на Вашу совесть)):

```
class apple {
    public static $apples;

    public $color;
    protected $riseDate;
    public $size;
    protected $state;

    public function __construct($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->riseDate = 0;
        $this->size = 1; // или 100 как вам удобнее
        $this->state = false; // $state = ON_TREE так красивее
        self::$apples[] = $this;
    }

    public function fall_to_ground()
    {
        $this->state = true; // $state = ON_GROUND или как вам удобно
    }

    public function eat($percent)
    {
        // Едим, если съедено, удаляем из массива $apples
    }

    public static function lost_hour()
    {
        // В цикле перебираете массив $apples, инкрементируете $riseDate. Если 5 часов
        // помечаете как не съедобное
    }
}

$apple_1 = new apple('green');
echo $apple_1->color; // green
echo apple::$apples[0]->color; // green

$apple_2 = new apple('white');
echo $apple_2->color; // white
echo apple::$apples[1]->color; // white

$apple_1->eat(50); // откусить пол яблока
echo $apple_1->size; // 1 - целое
```

Comment: Критика приветствуется!)

Comment: Критика будет - упустили момент, что яблоко портится... )

Да и в конструкторе слишком много операций. Оставить бы только $color и $apples, а остальные значения задать сразу при описании.

Comment: Спасибо за критику. Но, хотелось бы добавить, что до этого я на php практически ничего не делал, хотя даже вообще ничего не делал. Спасибо за пример. Буду разбирать. И после этого стоит ли устраиватся помощником php программиста, если у меня столько косяков ? Просто работа нужна очень сильно...выхода нет.

Comment: Ну не знаю насчет работы, смотрите сами. Зависит от работодателя, и того, у кого вы будете помощником. Просто если вас выставят с позором за некомпетенцию, не помешает ли вам сия "слава" устроиться на подобную работу в дальнейшем?! То @Равнодушный, ну да можно ввести отдельную переменную, но можно и использовать для этих целей $riseDate (если >= 5 - несъедобно). Вплане удобочитаемости кода, конечно, лучше будет завести отдельный флаг.